# Unable to complete Calendar sharing

Tags: 8.1, 8.0, calendars

This problem is occurring on 2 phones: a Lumia 810 running 8.0 and a Lumia 635 running 8.1 . Both behave similarly.
I have successfully shared 3 outlook calendars (doing so on my computer.) 2 are with Live accounts, 1 with an Outlook account.
The resulting emails were sent to the phones OK. When I opened the emails, they gave me the option to "Accept" sharing. I hit that button and wend to a Calendar website which gave me the option to "Set up Calendar on your device." That's where the process stalls. I tap the "Set up..." link, it responds to the tap by turning gray for a second and then... Nothing.
And the calendars are not linked. Progress is stalled.
I've checked this board for similar problems, the only one I found suggested changing the >Settings > email + accounts to "Download new contenT as items arrive". I've done that and it's not solved the problem. 
Any suggestions? Thanks